# using Sampler2DArray throwing compilation errors

Tags: opengl-es, glsl

I am trying to use sampler2DArray to sample the array texture to which I rendered something on to layer zero. But when I try to compile the new shader which I created to a sampler the array texture is throwing compilation errors.

```
const char *fragshader="\
#version 320 es\n\
precision mediump float;\n\
\n\
in vec2 texcoord;\n\
uniform sampler2DArray texArray;\n\
uniform int layer;\n\
//out vec4 color;
layout(location =0) out vec4 color0;\n\
\n\
void main()\n\
{\n\
//gl_FragColor = texture(tex, texcoord,1.0);\n\
  color0 = texture(texArray,vec3(texcoord.x,texcoord.y,layer));
}\n\
";
```

I am getting compilation errors.
getting garbage values when I try to get the uniform locations.

Errors:

ERROR: 0:5: 'declaration': either a default precision should be defined or a precision qualifier should be used

ERROR: 0:5: 'declaration': either a default precision should be defined or a precision qualifier should be used

ERROR: 0:13: 'texArray' :undeclared identifier.
ERROR: 0:13: 'texture' :no matching overload function found.
ERROR: 0:13: 'assign' :cannot convert from 'const float ' to 'fragout 4-component vector of float'
ERROR: 5 compilation errors. No code generated.

Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first error is caused by the lack of precision specifier for the declaration of `texArray`, as `sampler2DArray` types have no default precision.

The shader compiles OK for me with this fix applied:

```
uniform mediump sampler2DArray texArray;
```