# sampler2DArray on IOS OpenGLES3.0

Tags: ios, opengl-es, shader

We're upgrading (!) our code on IOS from OpenGLES2.0 to OpenGLES3.0 so we can use texture arrays.

We build against OpenGLES3.0 defines and open a GL3.0 context, and I can initialise a texture array fine, but the shader code gives an error on this line when I compile it at runtime.

```
uniform sampler2DArray mySamplerName;
```

It complains about a "syntax error" on mySamplerName as if it doesn't understand sampler2DArray as a keyword

If I use

```
uniform sampler3D mySamplerName;
```

it compiles ok, but that's not what I want.

Yes, I know OpenGL is deprecated, but does anyone know if this should work on IOS ?

Thanks

Shaun

Comment: Could you please provide a minimal compilable shader code on which it's reproduced? And exact compiler's output.

Comment: The whole shader is very large but this is the line that causes the error

"uniform sampler2DArray mySamplerName;"

and the error is

"ERROR: 0:51: 's_texture1' : syntax error"

Note it doesnt comp,lain about sampler2DArray which makes me think that it's adding sampler2DArray as a uniform name, as it doesnt recognize it as anything else, like a sampler "keyword"

Comment: I would recommend posting the entire compilation error logs. Might be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72099275/using-sampler2darray-throwing-compilation-errors

Comment: Have you forgotten the glsles 300 define? `#version 300 es`

Comment: Yes, I have no "#version 300 es" line in my code. This must be the issue. Ive added it now and have some different errors, so I'll fix those and see if it all works. Thanks !